# CSS, HTML - Create rotated divs

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'd like to create a html page like shown in the picture above. The two blue divs should be rotated and be automatically expandend when the browser window is expanded. I know there is the css transform: rotate() command.

Anyway, as soon as I start scaling the browser, the top and bottom edges of the divs can be seen.
Any help how this can be implemented is very appreciated.

Comment: Try to follow that rotate implementing [CSS: Rotate Element](http://www.fix-css.com/2011/11/css-rotate-element-to-45-degrees-code/). That's well formatted and cross browser implementing of rotation.

Comment: Thanks for your tip Andriy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/366/)**

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #1A4780;
    position: relative;
}

.content:before {
    border-bottom: 50vw solid transparent;
    border-left: 50vw solid #008EE0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.content:after {
    border-top: 50vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 50vw solid #1A4780;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: NIce, thanks much! Could you please explain how you managed to rotate the borders? Don't understand that completely....